# Linear Algebra - Understanding how to get Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
  4 & -9 & 0 \\
  -9 & 36 & 0 \\
  0  & 0  & 40  \\
 \end{pmatrix} $$

Solving, i can easily find that eigenvalues are $\lambda=40, 20 + \sqrt{337}, 20 +- \sqrt{337} $

I cannot understand why one of the eigenvectors is

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  0 \\
  1  \\
 \end{pmatrix} $$

I thought eigenvectors are solved by just plugging in the eigenvalues into my characteristic equation and then solving from there.

I did not have one of the best linear algebra teachers, so i did not learn much from him.

Thank you for whomever helps.

Comment: What is $$\begin{bmatrix}6&-9&0 \\ -9&36&0 \\ 0&0&40\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$? Is that a multiple of the vector?

Comment: No, it's an eigenvector of the matrix. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: x @DarthLazar: No? Please show what you get the result to be. When I do the matrix multiplication, I do get a scalar multiple of the vector.

Comment: Also, can you give the definition of "eigenvector" you're working with? What you write makes me think you must have a somewhat unusual definition ...

Comment: All i know when evaluate this through mathematica, one of the eigenvectors given is (0,0,1)

Comment: x @DarthLazar: That is not an answer to any of the clarifying questions I'm asking. **What is your definition of "eigenvector"?** What do you think the matrix product in my first comment yields?

Comment: it gives 40. So I can just assume it is just that?

Comment: x @DarthLazar. **WHAT. IS. YOUR. DEFINITION. OF. "EIGENVECTOR"?**

Comment: Also, a matrix multiplied by a column vector gives another column vector. 40 is just a number, not a column vector, so it cannot be the result of that multiplication.

Comment: @DarthLazar It's going to be very hard to help you if you (1) don't know the very basic definition of the things you're trying to work with, (2) you don't address good will questions directed to you to clear up doubts about what *you* know and what you don't,

Answer (score 1):

> I thought eigenvectors are solved by just plugging in the eigenvalues into my characteristic equation and then solving from there.

The eigenvalues are the roots of your characteristic equation. An eigenvector $x$ is a vector that satisfies the relation
$ Ax = \lambda x$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$. So for your eigenvalue $\lambda=40$ you get

$ \begin{pmatrix}
  4 & -9 & 0 \\
  -9 & 36 & 0 \\
  0  & 0  & 40  \\
 \end{pmatrix} \pmatrix{0 \\ 0\\ 1}=40\pmatrix{0 \\ 0\\ 1}$

Answer (score 0):

Finding an eigenvalue:

$$\begin{array}{|ccc|}
4-\lambda &-9&0\\
-9&36-\lambda&0\\
0&0&40-\lambda
\end{array}=0$$
Suppose that the eigenvalues are indeed $\lambda=40,20+\sqrt{337},20-\sqrt{337}$.

Finding the eigenvector of $\lambda=40$:

$$ \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-36&-9&0&0\\
-9&-4&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right)\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
u
\end{pmatrix}:u\in\mathbb{R}$$